# I want to hide asp:PlaceHolder in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to hide asp:PlaceHolder in client side (javascript). Is this Possible to hide ? My partial Code is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function ProcessAndRedirect() 
  {
    document.getElementById('phprice').style.display = 'none';
   }
   </script>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "phprice" runat = "server">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ProcessAndRedirect()">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: Do you need to use an `asp:PlaceHolder`? If you're only showing/hiding via javascript, then use a `div`.

Comment: if you're using .net 4.0 use property ClientIDMode="Static" .. that's it

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
    document.getElementById('<% phprice.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, Try like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= phprice.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none';
```

If you only want to show and hide using the `javascript`, i better suggest not to use placeholder. anyways i guess you are dealing with the ASP.net pages.

Comment: it showing error as  The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).